# Keycloak 401 (Unauthorized) Angular

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, keycloak, http-status-code-401, keycloak-angular

I'm trying to set up a keylock with angular.
Everything works if in the keycloak admin panel I don't select settings "Access settings
" --> "Root URL" and "Home URL" in my client's settings.
If they are selected, then I get an error "error", I attach a screenshot of the settings and the code too

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q9mN.png)

Initialize funktion

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular'

export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        realm: 'cld_poc',
        clientId: 'keycloak-express',
      },
      loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        pkceMethod: 'S256',
        checkLoginIframe: false,
      },
    })
}
```

Auth guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  UrlTree,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router'
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected override readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak)
  }

  async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url,
      })
    }

    const requiredRoles = route.data['roles']

    if (!(requiredRoles instanceof Array) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return true
    }

    // return this.authenticated
    return requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role))
  }
}
```

router

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MediaLibraryComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
...
]
```

app module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    KeycloakAngularModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0yrJ.png)

everything I tried I described above.
I rummaged all over Google and stackoverflow in search of a problem, so I decided to write personally.

Comment: I wrote incorrect settings, below are correct:

Comment: "Access settings " --> "Client authentication" and "Authorization "

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign [this role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtsYr.png) to the user you are trying to log in with.